# GNU screen: keybindings won't work

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to bind the space key to windowlist in GNU screen, i.e. `bind ' ' windowlist -b` so that `C-a (space)` does what `C-a "` normally does. However, when I place this in my `~/.screenrc` it simply does nothing. That is, `C-a (space)` retains the "next screen" functionality.

If it makes a difference, I am working over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Close your sessions and start again. I tested it exactly:

```
bind ' ' windowlist -b
```

...and it worked in my sessions